# Make 3 plots into the same graph with the facet_wrap function

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Can someone explain to me how can I use the `facet_wrap` layer in `ggplot` to make 3 plots in the same graph so that each plot should be in a row and so that the scales of each plot changes freely.**

Here are the 3 graphs that I have made because I wanted to see the relation between those three covariates: `median_income` , `pct_immigrant`, `income_inequality` and the percentage of votes for Marine Le Pen individually.
To be precise, those three covariates are not variables that is why I had to filter the data frame `elections_2017_long_metrop_covariates_lepen_long` first so that I can only keep each observation among the variable `covariates`

**Also if you have any suggestion to better the visualisation of the graphs**

```
graph1 = filter(elections_2017_long_metrop_covariates_lepen_long, covariates == "pct_immigrant")       
ggplot(graph1,aes(x = value,y = pct_votes)) + geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.5,colour = "#d90502") + expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0:100) +labs(x = "share of immigrants",y = "percentage of votes for Marine Le Pen")
```

[image]

```
graph2 = filter(elections_2017_long_metrop_covariates_lepen_long, covariates == "income_inequality")       
ggplot(graph2,aes(x = value,y = pct_votes)) + geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.5,colour = "#d90502") + expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0:100) +labs(x = "income inequality",y = "percentage of votes for Marine Le Pen")
```

[image]

```
graph3 = filter(elections_2017_long_metrop_covariates_lepen_long, covariates == "median_income")  
ggplot(graph2,aes(x = value,y = pct_votes)) + geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.5,colour = "#d90502") + expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0:100) +labs(x = "median income",y = "percentage of votes for Marine Le Pen")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You did not gave a complete reproducible example, but I think this should work for you.

To make facets you should pass the filter variable into the `facet_wrap()` function.

```
elections_2017_long_metrop_covariates_lepen_long %>% 
  filter(covariates %in% c('pct_immigrant', 'median_income', 'income_inequality')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value,y = pct_votes)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  facet_wrap(~covariates)
```

Answer (score 0):

The full solution considering colors can be:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Plot
ggplot(subset(elections_2017_long_metrop_covariates_lepen_long
              covariates %in% c('pct_immigrant', 'median_income', 'income_inequality')),
       aes(x = value,y = pct_votes,color=covariates))+
  geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.5)+
  expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0:100) +
  labs(x = "share of immigrants",y = "percentage of votes for Marine Le Pen")+
  facet_wrap(.~covariates,scales = 'free',ncol = 1)+
  scale_color_manual(values=rep("#d90502",3))
```

Or:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Code 2
elections_2017_long_metrop_covariates_lepen_long %>%
  filter(covariates %in% c('pct_immigrant', 'median_income', 'income_inequality')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value,y = pct_votes,color=covariates))+
  geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.5)+
  expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0:100) +
  labs(x = "share of immigrants",y = "percentage of votes for Marine Le Pen")+
  facet_wrap(.~covariates,scales = 'free',ncol = 1)+
  scale_color_manual(values=rep("#d90502",3))
```

No output showed in lack of data.